# Magento 2 Update data with custom module

Tags: magento2

How we can update Magento2 default table record with a custom module schema

like :

```
UPDATE sales_sequence_profile SET `prefix` = "US" WHERE `meta_id` = 5;
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

here is latest updated code

```
<?php
    namespace {VendorName}\{Modulename}\Setup;

    use Magento\Directory\Helper\Data;
    use Magento\Framework\Setup\InstallDataInterface;
    use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface;
    use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleDataSetupInterface;

    class InstallData implements InstallDataInterface
   {

       public function install(ModuleDataSetupInterface $setup,
         ModuleContextInterface $context)
      {
          $setup->getConnection()->update(
                $setup->getTable('sales_sequence_profile'),
          [
              'prefix' => 'US'
          ],
          [ 
              'meta_id=5'
          ]
       );
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

You have to use installData or upgradeData .

Create InstallData.php or upgradeData.php at app/code/{VendorName}/{Modulename}/Setup

Then add below code

```
<?php
namespace {VendorName}\{Modulename}\Setup;

use Magento\Directory\Helper\Data;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\InstallDataInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleDataSetupInterface;


class InstallData implements InstallDataInterface
{


    public function install(ModuleDataSetupInterface $setup, ModuleContextInterface $context)
    {
       $setup->getConnection()->update(
            $setup->getTable('sales_sequence_profile'),
            [
                'prefix' => 'US'
            ],
            [
                'meta_id=5'

            ]
        );
    }


}
```

Comment: Hello Amit

There are two corrections in your code 

1) There is no upgrade method in InstallData we have to update with install 
     Method.

2) There is a typing mistake in line no 5. (semicolon missing)

Comment: always welcome bro.